# How to use the subset parameter of igraph's maximal.cliques function?

Tags: igraph

I have a large graph and I would to find the maximal clique involving a pair of vertices.  I thought that the subset argument to igraph's maximal.clique function would do this, but either I'm using it wrong it or it does something completely different.  I've spent a fair amount of time searching the web without luck.

Here's a minimal example showing the problem:

```
> library(igraph)
> packageVersion('igraph')
[1] ‘1.0.1’
> g = graph.empty(n=10, directed=FALSE)
> g = add.edges(g, c(1, 2))
> str(g)
IGRAPH U--- 10 1 -- 
+ edge:
[1] 1--2
> # This correctly results a clique.
> maximal.cliques(g, min=2)
[[1]]
+ 2/10 vertices:
[1] 2 1
> # These don't return anything!
> maximal.cliques(g, min=2, subset=1)
list()
> maximal.cliques(g, min=2, subset=c(1, 2))
list()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subset` argument is not for calculating the maximal cliques on a subset of the graph; it simply restricts the set of vertices that are used as *starting points* in the course of the [Bron-Kerbosch algorithm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) when finding maximal cliques. The Bron-Kerbosch algorithm itself still searches the entire graph and is allowed to add or remove vertices from the current set that it considers as it pleases.

The *only* role of the `subset` argument is that it allows you to parallelize the maximal cliques computation on large graphs by partitioning the vertex set of the graph into a number of subsets and then running `maximal.cliques` on multiple CPUs or CPU cores with different subsets. It is not guaranteed that a maximal clique will be found if the starting subset includes any or all of its vertices; for instance, on my machine, the maximal clique 1--2 is found if I use a starting subset consisting of vertex 9 only:

```
> maximal.cliques(g, subset=c(9))
[[1]]
+ 2/10 vertices:
[1] 2 1
```

If you want to search for maximal cliques in a subgraph of the original graph, use `induced_subgraph` first, followed by `max_cliques`.